# How to keep focused after 'alt' was pressed?(Adobe AIR app)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I was making an application with AIR + Flex.

One Feature is like:

- When <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> key is down, the mouse cursor changes to B,
- When <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> key is up, the mouse cursor restores to A.

But the problem is that everytime a release <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> key, the mouse cursor will change back to system default (Arrow shape), and seems like the focus is on somewhere outside the stage.

That reminds me that, when <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> was pressed in a ordinary window, the menu-bar will be focused.

**How can I stop this default behavior ?**

p.s. I have tried the following ways and doesn`t work:

- 1) listen to stage's `KEY_DOWN`/ `KEY_UP` event, and add **`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`** in the event handlers
- 2) listen to stage's `KEY_DOWN`/ `KEY_UP` event, and add **`event.preventDefault()`** in the event handlers
- 3) listen to stage's `KEY_DOWN`/ `KEY_UP` event, and add **`this.setFocus()`** in the event handlers. And **`callLater(this.setFocus)`** doesn't work too.

Comment: Hi Vergil, I did some testing myself and ended basically at the same point you described above, my event handlers are fired but stopping the propagation of the event or attempting to prevent the default behavior produces the same results.  From looking at the Docs it appears the altKey is only supported in Windows for the events I was checking out as well so this may be an issue when it comes time to test across platforms, for that reason I suggest using some other modifier key or other keystroke.

Comment: I also just stumbled on this in the documentation which may lead to an answer but haven't seen any menu's that describe the one shown when the alt key is pressed: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Menus_2.html

Comment: This may also lead closer to an answer to the problem as presented: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/custom_chrome.html although this is discussing creating Chromeless windows it also has some info on how to block default behaviors in NativeWindows.

Comment: I would avoid ALT for a variety of reasons. Use SHIFT or some other key!

Comment: How about systemManager.stage.focus = this; where this is the application.

Comment: I use `fscommand("trapallkeys", "true");` to stop the ESC key in browser in fullscreen but it doesn't work for ALT

Answer (score 0):

On win impossible. But U can write shell/bash script for activating your app and run it from AIR. See NativeProcess class.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to deactivate event
And then do activate